# Android ADB has root access but no SU binary

Tags: adb, root-access

I recently purchased an Android TV box that claimed to come "pre-rooted", however there is no SuperSU apk or SU binary installed. The interesting thing is that I am automatically logged in as the root user when I connect to the device with ADB (I can run reboot commands etc), which tells me that I have at least some level of root access. Can anyone explain how this might have been set up and how I can grant root privileges to my apps as well?

Comment: Related: [If a user debug build comes with adb root access by default, does it contain the su binary?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230788/44325), [How to grant certain apps root permission through ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225313/44325)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two different sides of the card deck:

- apps need the `su` binary to be able to use "root powers"
- the ADB daemon does not; it gains root access while being started by the system in the corresponding mode

The latter is a simple setting in your device's `build.prop` file: `ro.secure=1` (default on most devices) tells the system to start the daemon in "secure mode", i.e. not with root powers – while `ro.secure=0` would turn off that security and run the daemon "as root" – which will be the case with your device.

Knowing that, the claim of being "pre-rooted" is partially true: you can use ADB to "push" the relevant files to your device. Four steps should do it:

```
adb shell "mount -o remount,rw /system"
adb push su /system/bin/su
adb push superuser.apk /system/app
adb reboot
```

After that reboot, your device should be "fully rooted" – and "root apps" should find everything they need to work, with you being in control of it via the superuser app.

Comment: In addition to Izzy's response, the firmware was compiled either with "Engineer" or "User-debug" builds/flavors, because "ro.secure=0" will not work on "Production" flavors/builds

Comment: also, where can we find the relevant `su` binary?

Comment: where can I find the su binary?

Comment: @Gizmo you could guess that from the code box: it's part of the SuperUser package. The `su` binary alone won't be much useful without the app controlling it.