# How is "rooted debugging" allowed on a non-rooted phone?

Tags: adb, rooting, root-access, usb-debugging, lineageos

I just installed Lineage 18.1 (Android 11) on an old phone.

Per the Lineage website, "Lineage is not rooted by default."

However, I am surprised to see the option "rooted debugging" is available in developer options and I can switch it on.

So my question is, how is it possible for me to allow rooted debugging if the phone is in fact not rooted.

What am I not getting?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [if a user debug build comes with adb root access by default, does it contain the su binary?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230788/44325), which linked to a more in-depth technical explanation on [What special privileges "/system/xbin/su" does have w.r.t. root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207623/44325) and [Why "adb root" does nothing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213116/44325).

Comment: Are you sure this option has any effect on a non-rooted device? In which section inside developer options do you see this option?